# Redisson release lock from different threads

Tags: java, redis, locking, redisson

I'm trying to create an infrastructure where different machines acquire shared locks through Redisson. Once the lock is acquired, some async tasks gets done, finally, when I finish the job, I'm releasing the Redisson lock through the thread currently running - but i receive the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: attempt to unlock lock, not locked by current thread by node id: xxxxx thread-id: 57
```

So, I understand the meaning of that, but since I want to perform asynchronous work, I cannot use the acquiring thread to perform the release.

Should I not use Redisson locks? What is the best match for async work like that?

Comment: [`Lock#unlock()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#unlock--) tells you that a lock will typically do that. So probably a different primitive like a Semaphore that is needed regardless of what library you use. Edit: hit enter too early.

Comment: Thanks! The Semaphore of Redisson is not asynchronous AFAIK so i cannot use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As zapl mentioned, [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html#unlock--) shows that this is the proper behavior of a java lock.
After discussing the issue on [Reddison's GitHub page](https://github.com/mrniko/redisson), it seems like Redisson Lock was not designed for that, and that the Redisson Semaphore will support async operations soon.

At the meantime, i plan to allocate a single thread to perform ALL locking and unlocking. Since Redisson has the support for async, non-blocking calls, this solution seems reasonable for now.

Answer (score 2):

Since your service is running on multiple nodes. Would suggest you to use lock.isHeldByCurrentThread() method before unlocking. A sample method would like

```
RLock lock = redissonClient().getLock(lockLabel);
try {
  if (lock.tryLock(lockAcquireWaitTime, lockLeaseTime, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) {
   //Action to be performed when lock is acquired.
    lock.unlock();
  }
  Thread.sleep(syncMonitorInterval);
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOG.error("Error..", e);
} finally {
  if (lock != null && lock.isLocked() && lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
    lock.unlock();
    LOG.debug("lock released");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use forceUnlock() instead of unlock(), it works and successfully release the lock locked by another thread, but may be not a recommanded way.

Another way please refer to https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/2224
you can use `lockAsync(threadId)` and `unlockAsync(threadId)` to walk around the thread id check.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Redisson Semaphore object. Since 2.2.14 version it supports asynchronous operations via `RSemaphoreAsync` interface.